# Testing interactions between multiple applications

Tags: unit-testing, testing, e2e

I have a project which is composed of several applications:

- a mobile (ionic) app connected to a Typescript server embedded in a raspberry (WebSocket connection)
- a desktop (electron) app connected to 1 to 100 couple app/embedded server (also WebSocket connection)

The desktop app drive the couples (telling it what to display etc..)

I need to test the whole system (end to end testing, network interruptions.. )
For instance what I need to see is when I send a message from the desktop app to 100 couples, the message is well taken into account by every couple.

The idea is to get a cluster composed of 100 apps, 100 raspberries and 1 desktop app, to test the whole system and stress it.

Any idea on how to proceed ? Technologies, frameworks...

Thanks a lot !